# How do I correct this one line PHP syntax?

Tags: php, syntax, parameters

newbie here. I have the following PHP-code for a script with Betfair-API.

```
if ($event->marketName == "Match Odds") {
    // print_r($event);
    $params = [
        "marketIds" => [$event->marketId],
        'priceProjection' => ['priceData' => ['EX_BEST_OFFERS']]
    ];
}
```

I need to add virtual bets. API-documentation says:

> You can return virtual bets in the response when using API-NG by including the `virtualise":"true"` in the listMarketBook request e.g.
>
> ```
> [
>    {
>       "jsonrpc":"2.0",
>       "method":"SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketBook",
>       "params":{
>          "marketIds":[
>             "1.114101556"
>          ],
>          "priceProjection":{
>             "priceData":[
>                "EX_BEST_OFFERS"
>             ],
>             "virtualise":"true"
>          }
>       },
>       "id":1
>    }
> ]
> ```

How can I change my code to work? I've tried a few dozen combinations, but no luck. Sorry for being newbie.

David

Comment: Looks like you just need to add the key/value to the priceData part of the array.

Comment: `$params['virtualise'] = true;` or add it to the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = [
    "marketIds" => [$event->marketId], 
    'priceProjection' => ['priceData' => ['EX_BEST_OFFERS']],
    'virtualise' => true,
];
```